# Recurring events reminder in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run a simple query to calculate what will be a reminder based upon one date (enrollment_date.) It's a recurring event every 90 days starting with the enrollment date but our staff needs only to see the next possible date. So if one date is in December they will only see that date until it passes and then only see the next after that date has passed. Is that possible? I'm using oracle sql

All that will be seen is:

Until December 12 2015

```
Client          Next Inquiry Date
Client A        December 12, 2015
```

After December 12 2015

```
Client         Next Inquiry Date
Client A       March 11 2016
```

It's not much but this is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
    client_name, enrollment_date,
    CASE 
        WHEN CURRENT_DATE <= DATE(day, 90, nextdue_date)
```

Comment: adding your table schema to the question would help

Comment: I have no time to elaborate but you need something like (forget about the syntax)`enrollment_date+90*(1+floor((now-enrollment_date)/90)`

Comment: which database is this? How about using `top 1` to see only the first record?

Comment: @Nimesh if I use top 1, how to I get the date to recurring in order to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are still quite a few unknowns with your scenario, but here is an example (for SQL Server) that will show you the next 100 90-day reminders.  You can use a CTE to generate a list of reminder dates for each client then use the MIN from that list for each client that is still greater than the current date.

```
DECLARE @enroll_date DATE = '2015-12-12' --For testing
--DECLARE @enroll_reminder DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 90, @enroll_date) 

;WITH cte AS (

SELECT 1 AS count_

UNION ALL 

SELECT count_+1
FROM cte
WHERE count_<100
)

SELECT 
  'Client A'--replace with your column name
 ,MIN(DATEADD(DAY, 90*count_, @enroll_date)) AS test

FROM cte

--GROUP BY your_column_name

HAVING MIN(DATEADD(DAY, 90*count_, @enroll_date)) > GETDATE()
```

In this scenario, the next reminder is 2016-03-11, then when that day passes it will show 2016-06-09, then 2016-09-07, etc.

Comment: Please specify which dbms this is for. (No one tagged in the question.)

Comment: How do i translate that declare statement to a where statement?

Comment: @dfundako it's oracle sql

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you...
Since this is Oracle (PL/SQL) we cannot use `TOP 1` and hence using `ROWNUM` property.

```
SELECT client_name as "Client"
     , enrollment_date as "Next Inquiry Date"
  FROM <table_name>
 WHERE enrollment_date < (SYSDATE + 90)
  AND ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY enrollment_date
```